# Migrate to xcode 9 for swift 2.3 apps

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode9, swift2

I have an app launched in appstore built on Swift 2.3 using Xcode 8, now apple made Xcode 9 mandatory for new and app updates to store

Is it must to migrate to Xcode 9? have any one submitted swift 2.3 apps to appstore in July?

Comment: What's the question? You already know what you have to do.

Comment: You can just try to create .ipa file then upload manually via Apple Configurator?

Comment: - Im trying to understand whether it is mandatory to upgrade to Swift3 and it mean apple stop supporting swift 2.3 apps? \n - Also is not clear whether it is only for new apps or existing app updates as well?

Comment: Yes you need to convert swift 2.3 to swift3 syntax which has major changes and then you can open project in xcode 9. if app is live and you make another version live it will give you warning for that and if you upload first version which is in 2.3 it will give error and it will not upload app at all.

Comment: I have 2 app in 2.3 i need to convert that in swift3 and then i can open app in xcode 9.1

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to migrate to XCode 9. All iOS app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK.

> iOS 11 delivers innovative features and the redesigned App Store to hundreds of
>       millions of customers around the world. Your apps can deliver more intelligent, 
>       unified, and immersive experiences with Core ML, ARKit, new camera APIs, new 
>       SiriKit domains, Apple Music integration, drag and drop for iPad, and more. 
>       Starting July 2018, all iOS app updates submitted to the App Store must be 
>       built with the iOS 11 SDK and must support the Super Retina display of
>       iPhone X.

Reference [Upcoming iOS 11 App Update Requirements](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05072018a)

Answer (score 0):

**If your app is in swift 2.x syntax and now you need to upload you must need to convert first to swift syntax 3 (using xcode 8.x) and then you can open it in xcode 9.x to upload your app**

**if your app is already live it may be give error or warning like below screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help - Appreciate it